# Что я делаю не так с backbutton?

Tags: phonegap, phonegap-api, android, backbutton

Простейший код, который должен возвращать в меню:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    location.replace('file:///android_assets/www/ru/menu.html');
}
</script>
```

Но всё равно приложение закрывается, т.е. не успев переехать в меню. Как исправить?

Comment: Что делаете не так? Пишите приложение на PhoneGap:) 
Третий параметр пробовали в true поставить?

Comment: @DroidAlex нефурычит

Comment: Хм, а точно тип event'а `"backbutton"`? Функция вызывается (добавьте в неё `alert` или отладочную печать)? Может, надо `document.location` или `window.location`?

Comment: Ничего не помогло

Comment: @VladD определить невозможно. При нажатии приложение закрывается мгновенно, так что остаётся лишь гадать, открылся ли alert

Comment: @danpetruk: а отладочная печать? Запишите что-нибудь в stdout или в файл (не забудьте закрыть файл, а то данные потеряются).

Comment: @danpetuk, попробуйте собрать минимально работающий пример воспроизводящий ошибку и выложить архивом проект, может кто посмотрит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file:///android_assets/www/ удали и все будет открываться

Comment: Кстати да, разве не должно быть  
 file:///**android_asset**/www/

Comment: должно быть ru/main.html если у тебя подпапка или же main.html если в корне wwww

Answer (score 1):

А Вы размещаете добавление слушателя в событии deviceready ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cordova Back Button Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown() {
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
</body>
</html>
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton